# Get invitation letter and then find a place to rent

Tags: spain

We are making an invitation letter for a friend (from Tunisia) to stay with us (in Spain) while she works as an intern, we already have the invitation letter from the company, but we still lack one of the requirements for the student visa (more than 90 days), which is a place to stay. For the moment she's gonna stay with us, but if she's able to afford it, and get a place for her own during her stay, would that be possible?, do we have to notify the police department? Because the invitation letter states she's gonna stay with us for that period. What kind of problems can we have? Thanks

Comment: It would probably be useful if you included additional information, like the citizenship of your friend, the purpose of her visit, its duration, the type of visa she's seeking to get...

Comment: @jcaron thank you, added!

Comment: This question should not have been migrated, as it was already asked on this site.